# WhirlyGlobe/Maply - GeoJSONSource error

Tags: swift, openstreetmap

I'm trying to make a swift app, and stucked with WhirlyGlobe/Maply.

My point is I'd like to use an openstreetmap with swift, so I need a framework, a free-paid one =) All I need from Maply is just load an osm, and then cover it with my own GeoJSON. So I have followed step by step Maply [tutorial](https://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/ios/styled_geojson.html>) "Styled GeoJSON", and have an error at this line of code:

*Add some GeoJSONSource objects for land use, buildings, and roads to your ViewController’s member variables:*

```
fileprivate var landUseSource: GeoJSONSource?
```

and error is -

```
Use of undeclared type 'GeoJSONSource'
```

I found nothing about this type of objects, and don't know, how to use my own geojson with this framework. 2D map and location work fine. Maply installed from binary distribution.

so, is this framework is still ok? or should I replace it with mapbox better?

Comment: You might want to do a `import GeoJSONSource` or something like that?

Comment: @Larme  i've tried, but have an error `No such module 'GeoJSONSource`

Comment: Try using git sub module. I found an old thread on the github. That might be useful for your reference. https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/issues/1049